# How should non autocorrelated time series data be modelled?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

I'm working on time series predictions for predicting the frequency of 911 calls in a town, based on previous data. But it would seem to me that this time series data isn't autocorrelated. The number of calls at time $t$, $y_t$, doesn't depend on the previous time points $y_{t-1}, ..., y_{t-k}$, it seems to depend only on the current timestep, $X_t$. Should this problem then be modelled as a time series problem, using models like ARIMA, or as a simple regression problem $\hat{y}_t = \hat{f}(X_t)$?
Even if you think this data has some degree of autocorrelation, let me ask a more general question: if a time series dataset has low autocorrelation, what kind of models should I use for it?

Comment: If there is no autocorrelation (which does make sense for your data) then you could analyze it with a regression model or any other appropriate statistical model. This does also depend on your goal.

Comment: look for Poisson process

Comment: Depending on your time granularity (hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly), you may have seasonality, or even multiple seasonalities.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Seasonality implies a form of autocorrelation.  Thus, we need clarification of the question. Nadir, are you asking about non - *autoregressive* series or non - *autocorrelated* series? As far as your last question goes, you seem to describe every non-time-series dataset, thereby reducing your question to "how do I perform statistical modeling for data that are not time series?" That is simply too broad to be answerable.  Could you please edit your post to make it more specific?

Comment: @whuber I want to know about time series which aren't autocorrelated, for example 911 calls. I understand that there is seasonality and there exists some amount of autocorrelation, but I think this can also be modelled by including variables such as weather, time of the year etc. Using autoregression (predicting $y_t$ as a function of $y_{t-i}, i=1,2,..,k$) would be naive, I don't see a reason the number of 911 calls in the last day (week, month) would affect the number of 911 calls today (this week, month). This was my question

Comment: You are confusing *causality* with *correlation*; it is not necessary that the number of calls yesterday *affect* the number of calls today, only that they be *correlated*, for example, if there are more calls in December & January when there is less sunlight and people who suffer from seasonal affective disorder (SAD) are feeling at their worst, or icy roads causing more car accidents.  You should check the autocorrelation using the standard methods (at least) before coming to any conclusions.

Comment: @jbowman yes, I understand that, thanks for the clarification. But again to my question: should autoregressive models be used only on autocorrelated data? If my data isn't autocorrelated, does it still make sense to use autoregressive models?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but your logic, as expressed above, isn't sufficient to conclude that the series isn't autocorrelated.

Comment: @jbowman great, thanks! I'll be sure to do some autocorrelation tests before I get into modelling. Many thanks!

Comment: @jbowman But just for the sake of the statistics, is there a "proof" that AR can only work on autocorrelated data? If there is autocorrelation, I think that it MIGHT be the case that an AR model can be successful, but it also MIGHT not be successful, because causality != correlation. But if there isn't any autocorrelation, then an AR model wouldn't EVER be successful, because correlation is necessary for causality? Can we measure causality? Sorry for the long post, I'm a mathematician that's new to stats and need some guidance

Comment: AR models don't assume causality.  Correlation is not necessary for causality either.  AR models can work in the absence of autocorrelation, they just overfit the data, which lessens predictive accuracy some, but maybe not enough to matter for your application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147913/discussion-between-nadir-basic-and-jbowman).